# APIM caching not working with same vary-by-query-parameters

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-api-management

I am working on APIM caching and while testing. I found caching not working. If below header or query parameters (userAuthorizationToken,ProductCode, PageNo, Limit) remain same it should return cache response.

I am using postman to test the endpoint by calling "GetProduct" passing parameters. then I enter more records in database and call the Getproduct again it return more records. However, caching duration not met.

Any advice.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" must-revalidate="true" allow-private-response-caching="true" caching-type="internal" >
            <vary-by-header>userAuthorizationToken</vary-by-header>
            <vary-by-query-parameter>productCode</vary-by-query-parameter>
            <vary-by-query-parameter>pageNo</vary-by-query-parameter>
            <vary-by-query-parameter>limit</vary-by-query-parameter>
        </cache-lookup>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base/>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <cache-store duration="2400" />
        <base/>
    </outbound>
    <on-error> ....etc
```

Unfortunately, I can't access APIM in azure portal.

Comment: Can you check the trace regarding cache miss?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access APIM in azure portal. because of my company policy. can I add tracing to http reponse.?

Comment: You have to pass ```Ocp-Apim-Trace: True``` in the header: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector

Comment: Thanks, I have found "Set query string parameter" and vary-by-query-parameter
what is the difference b/w two. In my case URI =product/?Page=1&Limit=200&Code123

Which one should I use for My controller code = Task<IActionResult> GetPrd([FromQuery] Query qDto)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetQueryStringParameter

Comment: "Set query string parameter" passes a new Query String to Backend. This has nothing to do with caching

Comment: "vary-by-query-parameter" checks the request url for query-parameters like ?productCode=123 and returns previous cached results

Comment: Thanks markus. you are really helpful. I was reading (very by query parameter(
vary-by-query-parameter Start caching responses per value of specified query parameters. Enter a single or multiple parameters. Use semicolon as a separator. If none are specified, all query parameters are used)

So, If I have 4 querystring parameters Page, Limit, ProductCode,ProductType
Should I use semicolon as separator such as  or different vary-by-parameter?

            <vary-by-query-parameter>limit;page;productCode;productType</vary-by-query-parameter>

Comment: This will not work: `<vary-by-query-parameter>limit;page;productCode;productType</vary-by-query-parameter>`

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks you for response. Sorry I am confused. Please help me understand. 
I have a webapi net core 6 project that has getproduct endpoint. which take paramater such as pageNo, limit etc. Also, in my project I am using APIM

Questions 1) Do I need to implement caching at .net application level such as [ResponseCache(Duration = 120, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-response-caching/

My understanding in NO, APIM will do the caching (If, YES) then How APIM manage caching or store caching ? some storage in cloud?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies


APIM has two modes for caching: `internal` :to use the built-in API Management cache.

`external`: to use the external cache as described in Use an external Azure Cache for Redis in Azure API Management. If you prefer `external`, you have to provide an own redis cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache-external

Comment: Please try this API with your provided policies: https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.developer.azure-api.net/api-details#api=evaluation&operation=62ce45471cb8cbe3725b55ed